# How to remove a somewhat duplicate row?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a relation such that it looks like this

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (
letter1 text,
letter2 text)

INSERT INTO table_name (letter1, letter2) VALUES ('A', 'B')
INSERT INTO table_name (letter1, letter2) VALUES ('B', 'A')

letter1     letter2
--------------------
A               B
B               A
```

However, I want to delete the duplicate combination such that (A,B) = (B,A) so that I am only left with either one.

I am very confused right now. I tried to use selection with a condition and I also tried creating another table to compare and then use selection but I am lost.

Comment: Questions should include code examples, table structure, sample data, and a tag for the DBMS implementation (e.g. MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, MS SQL Server, IBM DB2, etc.) being used.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry. I use sqlite3.

Comment: add the sqlite3 tag to your question, then.

Comment: As i understand, I think you need to check for the duplicate row before INSERT'ing into your database. What I mean is you may need to first do a SELECT and then if found a record in DB, do not INSERT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
delete t
    where l1 > l2 and
          exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.l2 = t1.l1 and t2.l1 = t1.l2
                 );
```

If you just want to select the distinct pairs, you can do:

```
select l1, l2
from t
where l1 < l2
union all  -- or union if you need to remove duplicates
select l2, l1
from t
where l2 > 1 and
      not exists (select 1
                      from t t2
                      where t2.l2 = t1.l1 and t2.l1 = t1.l2
                 );
```

Comment: Thank you. I got what I needed from you solution.